# Check if item exists for each partition

Tags: python, sql, excel, pandas

Suppose there are 5 shopping bag that need be filled with either 3 or 4 distinct items. It is already decided beforehand what items need to be in each shopping cart.

This info. is portrayed in an excel file in the following way.

| Bag | Item |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | milk |
|  | cheese |
|  | eggs |
|  | honey |
| 2 | ham |
|  | chicken |
|  | pork |
|  | fish |
| 3 | bread |
|  | mayo |
|  | ketchup |
| 4 | potato chips |
|  | broccoli |
|  | mixed greens |
| 5 | Jalapeno peppers |
|  | ice cream |
|  | yogurt |

A list of available items in the shop is provided also as a column in an excel file - not all items are available in the shop.

| Item |
| --- |
| milk |
| cheese |
| honey |
| bread |
| mayo |
| ketchup |
| potato chips |
| broccoli |
| mixed greens |

I want to return the shopping bags and items that can be completely filled. In the above example, we can see that bags 3 and 4 can be completely filled. How can I do this?

Open to using Python, Pandas & SQl. I did a vlookup in excel which was simple enough, but I have over a million rows and it would be impossible to sort through it all to see which bags are completely filled.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: This is almost identical to the bartender problem, where bartenders have ingredients on hand and we have a dictionary of drinks and the corresponding required ingredients for those drinks.  The goal is to find which bartenders can make which drinks, assuming if an ingredient is on hand there is enough for any / all drinks involving that ingredient.  There are many solutions.  I'll post one.  It's a little more involved than your problem, since you have only one shop (bartender).

Answer (score 0):

Compared to the bartender problem, think of a "bag with items" as a "drink with ingredients required", and the "shop with items" is like a "bartender with ingredients on hand".

Here's one logical solution, as an example:

```
CREATE TABLE cms_user (
   user_id        int PRIMARY KEY
 , name           varchar(20)
);

INSERT INTO cms_user (user_id, name)
     VALUES (1,'User1'), (2,'User2'), (3,'User3')
;

CREATE TABLE cms_user_ingredient_rs (
   user_id        int
 , ingredient_id  int
 , PRIMARY KEY (user_id, ingredient_id)
);

INSERT INTO cms_user_ingredient_rs (user_id, ingredient_id)
     VALUES (1,1), (1,2), (1,3), (1,5), (2,2), (2,3), (2,4)
          , (3,1), (3,2), (3,3), (3,5), (3,6)
;

CREATE TABLE cms_drink (
   drink_id       int PRIMARY KEY
 , name           varchar(20)
);

INSERT INTO cms_drink (drink_id, name)
     VALUES (10,'Test'), (15,'Test2')
;

CREATE TABLE cms_drink_ingredient_rs (
   drink_id       int
 , ingredient_id  int
 , PRIMARY KEY (drink_id, ingredient_id)
);

INSERT INTO cms_drink_ingredient_rs (drink_id, ingredient_id)
     VALUES (10,1), (10,3), (10,5), (15,1), (15,6)
;

WITH v2 AS (
         SELECT t1.drink_id      drink_id
              , t1.ingredient_id ingredient_id
              , v1.user_id       user_id
           FROM cms_drink_ingredient_rs AS t1
           CROSS JOIN cms_user AS v1
     )
SELECT v2.user_id, v2.drink_id
  FROM v2
  LEFT JOIN cms_user_ingredient_rs v3
    ON (v2.ingredient_id,v2.user_id) = (v3.ingredient_id,v3.user_id)
 GROUP BY v2.user_id, v2.drink_id
HAVING COUNT(if(v3.user_id IS NULL, 1, null))=0
;

+---------+----------+
| user_id | drink_id |
+---------+----------+
|       1 |       10 |
|       3 |       10 |
|       3 |       15 |
+---------+----------+
```

Note: There are other solutions to this.